i got "Expected '(' but got identifier"
function addAdmin(address _adminAddress) public onlyAdmin {
    require(msg.sender == administrateur || isAdmin(msg.sender), "Vous devez être l'administrateur ou un administrateur pour appeler cette fonction");
    
    AdminNode memory newAdminNode;
    newAdminNode.adminAddress = _adminAddress;
    newAdminNode.next = adminListHead;
    adminListHead = newAdminNode;
}


share the full code.

It is likely the syntax error is before the line that causes the message.
